# Is Nike clothing (shoes, shirts, sweatshirts or shorts) haram?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

Is Nike shoes or clothing haram? Like shoes, slippers, backpacks or shirts, jackets, shorts. I have a lot of shoes from Nike. Can you wear Nike as a brand for fashion or would that still be sin?

Comment: Not only is it haram, it is also shirk.  "Nike" is named for and honors a Greek (pagan) goddess.  Dedication to any brand is the devil's path, approaching idolatry.  Put your devotion to God, not human symbols ginned up by Satan's emissaries (ad men).

Answer (score 1):

No, nike is not haram, as long as it closes your awrat/awrah